# Find all natural $n$ for which the integral is non-zero

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

I have to find all natural $n$ such that 
$$I=\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^n}{z^{10} - 1}dz \neq 0$$

Since all the $10^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity lie in $|z|=2$, by residue theorem we have

$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^n}{z^{10} - 1}dz = 2\pi i \cdot\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\ \text{Res}(f,e^{k\pi i/5})=\frac{2\pi i}{10} \cdot\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{9}z^{n-9}\rvert_{e^{k\pi i/5}}\right) = \begin{cases}0\quad n\not\equiv9\pmod {10} \\ 2 \pi i\quad n\equiv9\pmod {10} \end{cases}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: That's fine${}$.

Comment: It's OK. You may also use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity . See 
Lord Shark the Unknown's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use the substitution $w=1/z$. That gives
$$I=-\int_{|w|=1/2}\frac{w^{-n-2}}{w^{-10}-1}\,dw
=-\int_{|w|=1/2}\frac{w^{8-n}}{1-w^{10}}\,dw.$$
When $n\ge0$ the function
$$\frac{w^{8-n}}{1-w^{10}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^{8-n+10k}$$
has a Laurent series about $0$, and the integral is nonzero
if its residue (the coefficient of $w^{-1}$) does not vanish. That's the
case iff $n$ is a positive integer congruent to $-1$ modulo $10$.